# I am new to CSS, how can I improve this code

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am new to programming and I am learning frontend web development using both w3schools and freecodcecamp. I came across a particular piece of code written in CSS that I can't seem to really understand how it works. Please help me explain the flow of the code in plain English.

```html
<style>
    .browser-article
    {
        padding:5px;
        margin:0;
        background-color:lightgray;
        
    }
    .browser-article>h1, .browser
    {
        padding:10px;
        margin:10px;
    }
    
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

`.browser-article` - A dot before the identifier means its a class and it can be used on multiple elements. Any HTML elements with the class name browser-article will have this styling applied. Eg `class="browser-article"`

This will help you under stand the padding and margin

[image: CSS Chart]

`.browser-article > h1, .browser` is just being more specific. The header (`h1`) inside the `browser-article` and also including `.browser`

This is a good place to start https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-css

Answer (score 1):

#### The selectors

The `.browser-article` selector selects all elements with the `browser-article` class. Take note of the dot (`.`) in front of the text.

Demonstration:

```css
.browser-article {
  color: red;
}

pre{
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="browser-article">
 <pre>.browser-article</pre>
</div>
<div class="not-browser-article">
 not <pre>.browser-article</pre>
</div>
```

`.browser-article>h1` selects all `h1` elements that are immediate children of elements with the `browser-article` class. `>` is the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator).

Demonstration:

```css
.browser-article>h1 {
  color:red;
}

pre{
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="browser-article">
  <h1>Child of <pre>.browser-article</pre></h1>
</div>
<h1>Not a child of <pre>.browser-article</pre></h1>
```

The comma `,` is simply a way of applying the same style to multiple selectors.

This:

```
.browser-article > h1, .browser{
    padding:10px; margin:10px;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
.browser-article > h1{
    padding:10px; margin:10px;
}
.browser{
    padding:10px; margin:10px;
}
```

---

#### The properties

`margin` is the distance an element maintains with other elements, while `padding` is the distance the elements inside of the element maintains with the element.

Demonstration:

```css
div{
  border:1px solid;
}
.margin{
  margin:50px;
}
.padding{
  padding:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="margin">
An element with margin
</div>
<div class="padding">
An element with padding
</div>
```

<sup>Take note of the distance between the element with the `margin` class and the element with the `padding` class. This is achieved with the `margin` property</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, after defining the styles, try something like the following:

```
<h1>This heading gets no style (would match h1 element selector, but not .browser-article>h1)</h1>

<div class="browser">
<p>This matches .browser</p>
</div>

<div class="browser-article">
<p>This matches .browser-article and is gray</p>
<h1>This matches .browser-article>h1, as it is contained inside an element with the browser-article class (matches both, both are applied here)</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate the feedback, I can gladly say that these have been very helpful solutions. Thank you!